# How to transform a list of numbers into seperate elements talend tmap

Tags: database, talend, tmap, data-integration

I have a list of codes for each state as an input stored in a table.

[image]

What I want as output is this , using tmap transformations

[image]

This is the job I made but it doesn't seem to work correctly like I want. The output should have 1000 rows.
[image]
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert your list to a string of comma-separated values (using tConvertType for instance) and then use tNormalize to split this string into individual rows.